# .value return string until I save it to variable

Tags: javascript, string, dynamic-typing

I have case that I'm not sure how to explain:
What bugs me is, I open the code, I write some values (example: 
How much was you bill: 100
How was your service: 10
How many people are sharing: 2) and before I click Calculate I open the console. If I write:

```
>bill.value
<"100"
```

I get a string, as expected. But then I click Calculate and what I get is:

```
100
5
```

Why 100??  Why does it suddenly return number insted of string?

How can I do math with it at the end. Only thing I'm turning into a number is Number(bill.value). Service and people should still be strings?

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

var tip = document.getElementById("tip");

var total;


button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var bill = document.querySelector("input");

  console.log(bill.value)

  var people = document.getElementById("people").value;

  var service = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;

  total = (service * Number(bill.value)) / people
  tip.textContent = total;
  console.log(total)
});
```

```html
<h1>Tip Calculator</h1>

<div>How much was your bill?</div>

<label for="bill">$</label>
<input type="number" id="bill">



<div>How was your service?</div>

<select>
  <option disabled selected value="0">Choose</option>

  <option value="0.30">30% - Outstanding</option>
  <option value="0.20">20% - Good</option>
  <option value="0.15">15% - It was okaya</option>
  <option value="0.10">10% - Bad</option>
  <option value="0.05">5% - Terible</option>
</select>

<div>How many people are sharing the bill?</div>
<label>
  <input type="number" id="people">people</label>

<button>Calculate!</button>

<span id="tip"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Now understanding you're asking about implicit conversion's I've updated my answer.

Take a look at the code below, you'll notice that `product` holds a value that is a number while sum holds a string.  An expression containing two strings separated by a `+` operator will always result in the concatenation of the strings (What most expect).

On the other hand the `*` operator is not valid for two strings so it attempts to convert the strings into values that do support the `*` operator, namely numbers.  If both strings are valid integers or floating point numbers the result is the product of the two numbers.  If not, the result will be NaN.

```
var a = '2.0';
var b = '3.0';

var sum = a + b;
var product = a * b;

console.log(product); // 6.0
console.log(sum); // "2.03.0"
```

Comment: How  can I do math with it at the end. Only thing I'm turning into a number is Number(bill.value).   Service and people should still be strings?

Comment: Igor, take a look at the fiddle I attached to the answer, you'll notice I converted both bill.value, and service into a float before any arithmetic..

Comment: Hi sheeldotme. Thank you very much for your help. parseFloat seems like a perfect solution, but please help me explain something, maybe I'm not getting it. What interests me is how come my example works? I can do arithmetic without parseFloat or turning people and service into a Number(). They are still strings but math works. What am I missing? 
Yeah, I know about the 1, I didn’t finish it until I explain to myself this first.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain why the multiplication of strings worked for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, that pushed me into right direction of investigating it further. So it’s just a case of simple coercion of strings into a number using the * , / and – operators  (excluding the + operator).

Comment: Exactly, that is it.